# Ionic 2 build failing because of Angular 2 validation attributes

Tags: android, forms, angular, ionic2

I don't get the errors when testing on the browser but as soon as I compile `ionic build android` I get an error:

Before adding Angular 2 specific validation `<ion-input type="text" name="username" required></ion-input>` the `required` attribute did not throw an error

```
ngc: Error: Error at /Users/simo/work/abalobi-web/.tmp/pages/login/login.ngfactory.ts:895:85: Property 'required' does not exist on
 type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.
Error at /Users/simo/work/abalobi-web/.tmp/pages/login/login.ngfactory.ts:900:85: Property 'pattern' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: a
ny; }'.
    at check (/Users/simo/work/abalobi-web/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:31:15)
    at Tsc.typeCheck (/Users/simo/work/abalobi-web/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:86:9)
    at /Users/simo/work/abalobi-web/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/main.js:33:23
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

**Form:**

```
  <form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm.value)" novalidate>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" name="username" ngModel #usernameRef="ngModel" pattern="^[A-Za-z]+$" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
      <div *ngIf="usernameRef.errors && (usernameRef.dirty || usernameRef.touched)">
        <div [hidden]="!usernameRef.errors.required">
          Field cannot be blank please enter username
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!usernameRef.errors.pattern">
          Username can only contain letters please enter correct username
        </div>
      </div>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Passowrd</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" name="password" ngModel #passwrodRef="ngModel" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div [hidden]="passwrodRef.valid || passwrodRef.pristine">
      Field cannot be blank please enter password
    </div>

    <button type="submit" ion-button color="primary" block [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid" >Login</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it seems the validation I was doing is not approach is either not the standard `Angular 2 / Ionic 2` form validation approach. I am not sure yet however I found a solution.

**Form:**

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="loginFn()">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div [hidden]="loginForm.controls.username.valid || (loginForm.controls.username.pristine && !loginForm.controls.username.touched)" class="validation-message">
                Username cannot be blank or contain numbers
        </div>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div [hidden]="loginForm.controls.password.valid || (loginForm.controls.password.pristine && !loginForm.controls.password.touched)" class="validation-message">
            Field cannot be blank please enter password
        </div>

        <button type="submit" ion-button color="primary" block [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Login</button>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  loginForm:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public _form: FormBuilder) {
    this.loginForm = this._form.group({
      "username": ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]*')])],
      "password": ["",Validators.required]
    });
  }

  loginFn() {
    console.log(this.loginForm.value)
  }
}
```

Sources: [Joshmorony](http://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/), [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZ6S_caHaAQ), [Scotch](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol)

Answer (score 0):

< ion-input /> does not have @Input properties like require or pattern

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/input/Input/#input-properties

Comment: Use ngControl @Input property to bind formControl on ion-input.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from your template. AOT compilation is more strict than JIT.

I ran into it when I was doing this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="job.owner"
       [class.form-control-danger]="owner.errors && (owner.dirty || owner.touched)"
       placeholder="Job owner" id="selected-owner" name="owner" #owner="ngModel" required>
<div *ngIf="owner.errors && (owner.dirty || owner.touched)">
   <small [hidden]="!owner.errors.required" class="form-control-feedback">A job owner is required. What team or area should "own" this job?                     </small>
</div>
```

The `owner.errors` object in the template is type `any`. The way to access a property there is `owner.errors['required']`. So the markup that passes the AOT compiler looks like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="job.owner"
       [class.form-control-danger]="owner.errors && (owner.dirty || owner.touched)"
       placeholder="Job owner" id="selected-owner" name="owner" #owner="ngModel" required>
<div *ngIf="owner.errors && (owner.dirty || owner.touched)">
   <small [hidden]="!owner.errors['required']" class="form-control-feedback">A job owner is required. What team or area should "own" this job?                     </small>
</div>
```